# Java Cannot be resolved as a type

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Trying to follow tuto but seems not working for me. It's Maven tuto, you can go to 11min to see the orignal code:

[Tuto Link Maven](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EMiAFLQp8ow&list=PLxhnp_qsD8EOkX0_RagnbUITXircj-XLC&index=3)

Please find below my code:

```
    package org.example.demo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.commons.io.input.ClosedInputStream;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
        
        Properties vProp = new Properties();
        InputStream vInputStream = null;
        try {
            vInputStream = App.class.getResourceAsStream("/info.properties");
            vProp load(vInputStream);
            
        } finally {
            if (vInputStream != null) {
                vInputStream close();
}}

System.out.println("Application version :"+vProp.getProperty("org.example.demo.version+"+"?"));}

}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Include errors and similar _as text_, not as screenshots.

Comment: you forgot to type dot after `vProp`, and after `vInputStream`.

Comment: Also keep in mind that `vInputStream.close()` throws IOException, so you either need to put that in another try/catch block or use a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: Thanks guys Sorry I'am felling so stupid ... @CharlieArmstrong I don't even know what means this code, I'am DevOps trying to learn in deep dive Maven for CI/CD Thanks a lot all.

Comment: I was basically trying to point you in the direction of Hawk's answer.  They just wrote it out for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missing dots there...
`vProp.load(vInputStream)` and `vInputStream.close()`

I would also suggest using try-with-resources for the vInputStream, no need for calling close then:

```
try (InputStream vInputStream = App.class.getResourceAsStream("/info.properties")) {
    vProp.load(vInputStream);
}
```

Comment: Running give me :  `Hello World!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434)
 at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)
 at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
 at org.example.demo.App.main(App.java:19)
`

Comment: My bad my folder was named ressources and it must be resources